# Finding the matrix exponential $(e^{tA})$ of a matrix $tA$ with complex values.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

> I want to know how I can express a matrix exponential $e^{tA}$ for a matrix $tA$, in terms of real valued functions for a matrix with complex eigenvalues.

(Example, the initial value problem ODE $x'(t)=Ax(t), x(0)=a$, where $A$ is a constant matrix, has the solution $x(t)=e^{tA}a$, so the knowing how to calculate $e^{tA}$ helps gives the solution).

**What I know:**

The matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
-b & a
\end{bmatrix}$ has complex eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}= a \pm ib$, so we can express $e^{tA}$ as $$e^{tA}= \begin{bmatrix}
e^{at} \cos(bt) & e^{at} \sin(bt) \\ 
-e^{at} \sin(bt) & e^{at} \cos(bt)
\end{bmatrix}.$$  Which is good as all functions are real valued.

However what is the process for the general $n$ by $n$ matrix?
There is the general formula for matrix exponential
$$e^{tA}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{t^k}{k!}A^k=I=tA+\frac{t^2}{2!}A^2+\frac{t^3}{3!}A^3 +... $$
but if $A$ is not nilpotent matrix we get a series solution, which for obvious reasons I would prefer to avoid.

**Additional edit based on comments:**

- [Example 1](http://www.math.umn.edu/~leif0020/Spring2011/matrixexp.pdf) How does this approach generalize to a $n$ by $n$ matrix? Why does $A=QAQ^{-1}$?
- [Example 2 (look at example 4 in the document)](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/ode/ExpMatrix.pdf) How do I express a fundamental matrix in terms of real valued functions?

Comment: @Moo Sorry, how embarrassing. I am removing my example, and reformatting my question. But my questions remains how do I do this for a general n by n matrix.

Comment: If you diagonalize $A$ and calculate $\exp(tA)$ as in the example you removed, you get a real matrix. Are you asking how to avoid diagonalizing? How to exponentiate a Jordan block matrix? Something else...? (Separately, the $2 \times 2$ example is missing a minus sign in the lower-left entry.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I removed that example cause the solution was is terms of real valued functions and may have confused people trying to answer a question. I am okay using any method so long as it works.

Comment: @Moo I previously saw both of those examples before posting this question and I am still confused. I have edited my question to comment on these examples